# css background-image does not work in Rmd slidify

Tags: html, css, rstudio, knitr, slidy

All,

I cannot understand why the image is not displayed in the background of my document, generated within `RStudio` (via the `knitr` button, to generate a `slidy` html document).

here is my reproducible example:

**test.Rmd**

```
---
title: "test"
output: 
  slidy_presentation:
    css: testcustom.css
    font_adjustment: -3
---

## Introduction {#intro}

### Hello World! 

This works: background-color: #6495ed;  
This does not work: background-image: url(pic/Presentation.jpg);
```

**testcustom.css**

```
#intro {
    background-image: url(pic/Presentation.png);
    background-color: #6495ed;
}
```

**image** is the following: http://displaynote.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Presentation.jpg, located in pic/Presentation.jpg

How can I fix this problem? It neither works in `IE` nor in `Chrome`.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your `testcustom.css` file using the same same file path as `pic/Presentation.jpg`?

Comment: test.Rmd and testcustom.css are in the same folder (project's root), with the pic folder as well. Presentation.png file is in the pic folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's actually working, but your image is so large that it's offscreen! Try this content for `testcustom.css` to scale the JPG file so it fits the screen:

```
#intro {
    background-image: url(pic/Presentation.jpg);
    background-color: #6495ed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```